# Speeding up group_by operations dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a tibble with a lot of groups, and I want to do group-wise operations on it (highly simplified mutate below).

```
z <- tibble(k1 = rep(seq(1, 600000, 1), 5),
            category = sample.int(2, 3000000, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(k1, category)
t1 <- z %>% 
  group_by(k1) %>%
  mutate(x = if_else(category == 1 & lead(category) == 2, "pie", "monkey")) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This operation is very slow, but if I instead do grouping "manually", the process is hard to read, more annoying to write, but much (20x) faster.

```
z %>%
  mutate(x = if_else(category == 1 & lead(category) == 2 & k1 == lead(k1), "pie", "monkey"),
         x = if_else(category == 1 & k1 != lead(k1), NA_character_, x))
```

So clearly there is some way with keys to speed up the process. Is there a better way to do this? I tried with data.table, but it was still much slower than the manual technique.

```
zDT <- z %>% data.table::as.data.table()
zDT[, x := if_else(category == 1 & lead(category) == 2, "pie", "monkey"), by = "k1"]
```

Any advice for a natural, fast way to do this operation?

Answer (score 5):

Doing these grouped comparisons is going to be relatively expensive. It's better to vectorize over the whole table if possible. Notice that `ifelse` is faster than `if_else` and `data.table`'s `shift` is faster than `lead`.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

z <- setorder(data.table(k1 = rep(seq(1, 600000, 1), 5),
                         category = sample.int(2, 3000000, replace = TRUE)))
t1 <- copy(z)
t2 <- copy(z)
t3 <- copy(z)
t4 <- copy(z)
t5 <- copy(z)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  if_else = t1[, x := if_else(category == 1L & lead(category) == 2L, "pie", "monkey"), k1],
  ifelse = t2[, x := ifelse(category == 1L & lead(category) == 2L, "pie", "monkey"), k1],
  shift = t3[, x := ifelse(category == 1L & shift(category, -1) == 2L, "pie", "monkey"), k1],
  ifelse3 = t4[, x := ifelse(category == 1L, ifelse(k1 == shift(k1, -1), ifelse(shift(category, -1) == 2L, "pie", "monkey"), NA_character_), "monkey")],
  logic = t5[, x := c("monkey", NA_character_, "monkey", "pie")[((k1 == shift(k1, -1, 0L))*((shift(category, -1, 0L) == 2) + 1L) + 1L)*(category == 1) + 1L]],
  times = 1,
  check = "identical"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#>  if_else 25162.7484 25162.7484 25162.7484 25162.7484 25162.7484 25162.7484     1
#>   ifelse 18150.7634 18150.7634 18150.7634 18150.7634 18150.7634 18150.7634     1
#>    shift  9057.7585  9057.7585  9057.7585  9057.7585  9057.7585  9057.7585     1
#>  ifelse3  1544.2912  1544.2912  1544.2912  1544.2912  1544.2912  1544.2912     1
#>    logic    81.9844    81.9844    81.9844    81.9844    81.9844    81.9844     1
```

The complexity in the logic is mostly due to the `NA` behavior. If `monkey` could take the place of `NA`, `t5` could be instead:

```
t5[, x := c("monkey", "pie")[((k1 == shift(k1, -1, 0L))*(shift(category, -1, 0L) == 2)*(k1 == shift(k1, -1, 0L))) + 1L]]
```

Comment: This is awesome and I need to study this. Hard to imagine getting much faster.

Comment: Seems to me the faster the solution here, the less readable, but glad you found it insightful. A truth table of the three logicals makes it easy to see.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: duckdb for the win! 10x faster than @akrun's data.table solution with the same output.

EDIT #2: small nit in OP where lead default not specified, leading to NA's that duckdb was replicating but which are treated as "monkey" in @akrun's data.table answer.

For benchmarking curiosity I looked at the `duckdb` and `collapse` packages, which both offer a version of dplyr masking / translation to a faster back-end. The collapse version was a smidge faster but `duckdb` was 10x as fast.

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq     max neval
 duckdb 809.5969 825.1131 851.222 845.6702 868.2173 900.495    10


Unit: seconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 collapse 8.363416 8.456532 8.633155 8.582542 8.835366 8.926974    10
       dt 9.211959 9.243295 9.330174 9.324183 9.433316 9.457501    10
```

---

I split the benchmarking into two parts because it looked like I couldn't have both `collapse` and `duckdb` masking dplyr at the same time.

Part 1

```
library(DBI); library(duckdb)
con <- dbConnect(duckdb())
duckdb_register(con, "z_duck", z)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times = 10,
  duckdb = tbl(con, "z_duck") |>
    group_by(k1) |>
    mutate(x = if_else(category == 1 & lead(category, default = 0) == 2, # EDIT to set default when there lead(Category) is NA at the end of a group, to match data.table answer
                       "pie", "monkey")) |>
    ungroup() |>
    collect())
```

Part 2 (after restarting R fresh)

```
library(data.table)
library(collapse)
options(collapse_mask = "all")

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times = 5,
  collapse = z |> 
    group_by(k1) |>
    mutate(x = if_else(category == 1 & lead(category) == 2,  
                       "pie", "monkey")) |>
    ungroup() |>
    collect(),
  
  dt = setDT(z)[, x := c("monkey", "pie")[ 
    1 + (category == 1 & shift(category, type = "lead") %in% 2)], by = k1]
)
```

I adjusted the duckdb formula by adding `default = 0` to the `lead()` term to conform to the data.table answer. That confirms the same calc is happening:

```
compare = data.frame(k1 = z$k1, category = z$category, 
                     dt = dt$x, duckdb = duckdb$x)
library(dplyr)
compare %>%
  count(duckdb == dt)
#  duckdb == dt       n
#1         TRUE 3000000
```

Answer (score 3):

We can speed up without having to use `ifelse`

```
library(data.table)
> system.time(setDT(z)[, x := c("monkey", "pie")[ 
     1 + (category == 1 & shift(category, type = "lead") %in% 2)], by = k1])
   user  system elapsed 
 18.203   0.146  16.635 
> system.time({t1 <- z %>% 
   group_by(k1) %>%
   mutate(x = if_else(category == 1 & lead(category) == 2, "pie", "monkey")) %>% 
   ungroup()
 })
   user  system elapsed 
 37.319   0.321  37.523
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to load {dtplyr}, which lets you use `dplyr` syntax and converts it to data.table syntax. To use {dtplyr}, add `lazy_dt()` before the {dplyr} steps and use `as_tibble()` at the end of the pipeline to evaluate the generated data.table code.

duckdb is faster though, comparison at bottom

**Show generated data.table code**

(not necessary, just used to in this answer to explain the process)

```r
library(dtplyr)
library(dplyr, w = F)
z <- tibble(k1 = rep(seq(1, 600000, 1), 5),
            category = sample.int(2, 3000000, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(k1, category)

z %>% 
  lazy_dt() %>% 
  group_by(k1) %>%
  mutate(x = if_else(category == 1 & lead(category) == 2, "pie", "monkey")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  show_query()
#> copy(`_DT1`)[, `:=`(x = fifelse(category == 1 & shift(category, 
#>     type = "lead") == 2, "pie", "monkey")), by = .(k1)]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>

**Compare times**

```
bench::mark(
duck = 
  tbl(con, "z_duck") |>
    group_by(k1) |>
    mutate(x = if_else(category == 1 & lead(category) == 2,  
                       "pie", "monkey")) |>
    ungroup() |>
    collect()
, dt = 
  z %>% 
    lazy_dt() %>% 
    group_by(k1) %>%
    mutate(x = if_else(category == 1 & lead(category) == 2, "pie", "monkey")) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    as_tibble()
, dplyr =
  z %>% 
    group_by(k1) %>%
    mutate(x = if_else(category == 1 & lead(category) == 2, "pie", "monkey")) %>% 
    ungroup()
)
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expres…¹      min   median itr/s…² mem_a…³ gc/se…⁴ n_itr  n_gc total_…⁵ result  
#   <bch:ex> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:tm> <list>  
# 1 duck     691.13ms 691.13ms 1.45     34.4MB   0         1     0 691.13ms <tibble>
# 2 dt         10.64s   10.64s 0.0939  107.6MB   0.939     1    10   10.64s <tibble>
# 3 dplyr       1.68m    1.68m 0.00995 880.3MB   1.20      1   121    1.68m <tibble>
```